# How to ease out a loading screen in Angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I created a loading screen in index.html in Angular like:

```
<app-root>
    <div class="app-loading">
      <svg class="logo" viewBox="0 0 100 100" >

      </svg>
    </div>
</app-root>
```

and applied some style. But after the page loads, the svg just disappears suddenly.

```
<style type="text/css">
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}
.app-loading {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.app-loading .logo {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  transform-origin: center center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
</style>
```

How could I make and ease-out transition when it disappears?

Comment: @dota2pro I added <style> class also

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SVG disappears because the HTML defined within `app-root` in your `index.html` is replaced with the rendered `app-root` component after application bootstrap.

To transition this, you can move `.app-loading` outside of `app-root` and transition it out *over* your bootstrapped application how you wish. In the demo below, it's just absolutely positioned fullscreen.

You can wait for the `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(...)` promise to complete to trigger the transition.

## index.html

```
<div class="app-loading">
    ...
</div>

<app-root></app-root>
```

## main.ts (or where your app is bootstrapped)

```
// loading element container to transition
const loadingElement = document.querySelector(".app-loading");

platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  // trigger the transition
  .then(() => loadingElement.classList.add("loaded"))
  // remove the loading element after the transition is complete to prevent swallowed clicks
  .then(() => setTimeout(() => loadingElement.remove(), 1000));
```

[image: Edit Angular]

Comment: Excellent, Austin.  Best solution yet.  Personally I would keep the logic here in one .then call, but we'll call that preference.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Using CSS, animate the Fade-out

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-anim-fade-in-out